# Run angular-cli for app in sub-folder

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli

I have the following application folder structure.

```
-- Web App
---- node_modules
---- src (source files)
---- angular-cli.json
---- package.json
-- node_modules
-- ServiceApp1
---- src (source files)
-- ServiceApp2
---- src (source files)
-- package.json
```

The service apps share dependencies which go in the root level package.json.  This is default behavior for webpack module building.  If it doesn't see a node_modules folder in the current folder, it will look to the parent.  This works great because I have these shared dependencies and only one node_modules folder for the service apps.  I want all apps to share the same package.json and node_modules.

The web app, however, uses angular-cli.  If I remove all the dependencies from it's local package.json, I get the following error:

```
You have to be inside an Angular CLI project in order to use the serve command.
```

If I move angular-cli.json to the root and change "apps": "root" from "src" to "web\src" I get the following error:

```
> ng serve --base-href=web

** NG Live Development Server is running on http://localhost:4200. **
49% building modules 549/837 modules 288 active ...ngular/material/core/portal/portal.jsError: No module factory available for dependency type: ContextElementDependency
    at Compilation.addModuleDependencies (/Users/dev/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:206:21)
    at Compilation.processModuleDependencies (/Users/dev/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:195:8)
    at _this.buildModule.err (/Users/dev/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:335:13)
    at building.forEach.cb (/Users/dev/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:140:27)
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at callback (/Users/dev/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:140:13)
    at module.build (/Users/dev/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:167:11)
    at ContextModule.<anonymous> (/Users/dev/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/webpack/lib/ContextModule.js:118:3)
    at ContextModule.result.resolveDependencies (/Users/dev/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/plugin.js:197:25)
    at ContextModule.build (/Users/dev/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/webpack/lib/ContextModule.js:99:7)
    at Compilation.buildModule (/Users/dev/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:142:10)
    at factoryCallback (/Users/dev/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:324:11)
    at /Users/dev/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/webpack/lib/ContextModuleFactory.js:96:12
    at /Users/dev/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:204:11
    at done.then (/Users/dev/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/plugin.js:199:28)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)
49% building modules 550/837 modules 287 active ...ngular/material/core/portal/portal.js/Users/dev/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:329
                                        if(_this.profile) {

TypeError: Cannot read property 'profile' of null
```

What is the best way to build an angular-cli project that exists in a sub folder?  I know the angular-cli doesn't support building multiple projects, and that's ok, I only have 1 web/cli project.

Answer (score 0):

```
ng serve--prod --base-href=../subDirName/
```

Comment: just add your main root path to the base-href

Comment: same error as long as I'm not using --prod, using that switch gives me an entirely different error (related to AngularFire2)

Comment: I added the rest of the error log in case that is helpful

Comment: This works with a very basic app with a single component and no routing.  As soon as I add routing (which worked before), I get this error: EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find module 'app/login/login.module'.

Comment: This also keeps putting /web in my URL!  Yuck!

Comment: I removed base-href as well as all route lazy loading and this works.. at least I can get them to share node_modules now